# Java Shopping Cart Array List

Tags: java, arrays, object

Im very new to java and im currently designing a shopping cart that allows you to add prodcuts to it and display whats in the shopping cart.

At the moment I create a array list like this :

```
final ArrayList<Object> cart = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

I then add a object "hats" to the shopping cart

```
hats Hat1 = new hats ("Hat",orderprice,colourtext,quantitynum,sizetext);

cart.add(Hat1); .
```

My question is how do I then get the array to display the Hat and its attributes?

Cheers

Comment: If you want a cheap nasty way of doing this, have a look at reflection to string from commons-lang. Add that to your hats class and then a toString should print out all the properties.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
final ArrayList<Object> cart = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Is likely wrong, unless you really do want your `ArrayList` to hold any and all object types. If you're just putting hats into the ArrayList, then by he code you've given it should be:

```
final ArrayList<hats> cart = new ArrayList<hats>();
```

...though I'd suggest changing your naming to follow Java conventions, classes should start with a capital and variables with a lower case letter, not the other way around.

You can then just retrive hats by calling the `get()` method on your `ArrayList` object, which will return an object of type `hats`.

If you really do need the generic type to be `Object` for some reason, then you can do a cast on the get method:

```
hats myHat = (hats)cart.get(0);
```

...but that's much nastier from a coding perspective, and offers much less type safety than choosing the right generic parameter to start with.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how do I then get the array to display the Hat and its
>   attributes?

Something like below?

```
final ArrayList<Object> cart = new ArrayList<Object>();
Hat hat =(Hat) cart.get(0);
hat.getWatever();
```

However, i would strongly advice you to have an arraylist of Hat instead of Object.

```
 final ArrayList<Hat> cart = new ArrayList<Hat>();
hats Hat1 = new hats ("Hat",orderprice,colourtext,quantitynum,sizetext);
cart.add(Hat1); .
    Hat hat =cart.get(0);//notice don't need to cast
    hat.getWatever();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I advice you never use Object as a generic parameter to collection(except cases where it is really needed).

Thus you will have a List of Hats:

```
ArrayList<Hats> cart = new ArrayList<Hats>();
```

If you would like to do something with whole collection of Hats objects you will have to create a sort of container class to implement logic conserning whole collection, because ArrayList class doesn't possess such logic.

So I would advice you to create a class Cart, which would contain a list of Hats and methods with logic you want to apply to the whole collection of cart items.

For example:

```
public class Cart {
    private ArrayList<Hats> _hats = new ArrayList<Hats>();

    public List<Hats> getHats
    {
        return _hats;
    }

    public Cart()
    {

    }

    public void DoSomthingWithCart()
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

In this class _hats will contain your cart items and in DoSomthingWithCart method you should implement your cart logic.

If you will go this way you will have a separate class for your cart with collection of objects and cart logic.